# Rails Gmail contact form - works on localhost but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am having a strange problem, I am coding a GMAIL contact form - which will use an existing Gmail username and password to send emails to a pre-specified Gmail account.

The issue I am having is that when I run everything locally it works just fine. Once I deploy to `Heroku` on the other hand ... I am not receiving the messages. When I run: `heroku logs -t` it seems to show that the message has been sent but nothing is still coming through.

Configuration:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options = { :host => 'domain.herokuapp.com' }  
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :domain             => 'domain.herokuapp.com',
  :user_name            => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
  :password             => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
  :authentication       => "login"
}
```

Note:

`domain.herokuapp.com` has just been subbed in for my actual domain.

Screen shot of server logs:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of why this is not working or can point me to a resource to get this resolved?

Comment: Do your environment variables exist on heroku server? `ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME']` and `ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD']`

Comment: @BorisBresciani Yes, all of my environment variables are on Heroku

Comment: So do you have an update?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it was connected to the configuration in config/enfironments/production.rb file i had

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://barteringapps.herokuapp.com' }
```

I was able to solve this problem by changing the address. In development it should be http://127.0.0.1:3000, while it should be your domain in production.

Also your gmail domain is not correct, you should have `gmail.com` as domain

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
  authentication: "plain",
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

I followed this post, but be careful when configuring the default_url_options as it would give me problems with facebook omniauth

https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/setting-up-mailer-using-devise-for-forgot-password/

Comment: No, that does not seem to be the issue. I tried your approach but still same effect

Comment: @jdave it is not a problem with the gmail account? did you allow less secure apps?https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en
Your gmail account is not sending any email?
Did you change the domain?

Comment: @jdave is your domain www.jaycdave.com ? As I say I am using gmail.com, if your domain is the one above, could you try dropping the www.?